# Set the value of a unicode character for sort in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, unicode

I'm trying to sort an array of strings alphabetically in JS.  Some of the array items are simply the string '-'.  Normally these values appear before 'a' in an alphabetical search, but I would like '-' to appear at the end.  Is there a way to give a character a specific unicode value so that you can customize sort results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can completely customize the sort results by providing a sort callback and checking for `"-"`:

```
yourArray.sort((left, right) => {
    if (left === "-") {
        return right === "-" ? 0 : 1;
    }
    return right === "-" ? -1 : left.localeCompare(right);
});
```

Live Example:

```js
const yourArray = [
  "testing",
  "-",
  "one",
  "-",
  "two",
  "three"
];
yourArray.sort((left, right) => {
    if (left === "-") {
        return right === "-" ? 0 : 1;
    }
    return right === "-" ? -1 : left.localeCompare(right);
});
console.log(yourArray);
```

More [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).